# Como usar repositório privado do Github no Packagist e reaproveitar o código no composer

Tags: github, composer, packagist

Tenho alguns repositórios privados no github, gostaria de reaproveitar o código em minhas aplicações que estão sendo feitas no Symfony, pois vou precisar de módulos que já existem em  mais de um projeto e me facilitaria muito a manutenção deles se eu pudesse gerenciar via composer.

A questão é que eu não conheço quase nada de composer e menos ainda de packagist.

Minhas dúvidas são as seguinte:

1. É possível eu usar o meu repositório privado do [github](https://github.com) no [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)?
2. É possível relacionar o repositório privado com o [packagist](https://packagist.org)?
3. Como fazer isso funcionar?

Achei um [tutorial sobre como distribuir os dados via composer](http://tableless.com.br/composer-um-pouco-alem-basico/) é por ele que estou me orientando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível utilizar repositórios privados. Você deve declarar o caminho do seu repositório na chave `packages` do composer.json, dessa maneira:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/rodrigorigotti/meu-repositorio-privado"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "rodrigorigotti/meu-repositorio-privado": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Um detalhe: o nome do pacote na chave `require` deve ser o nome do pacote que está no `composer.json` da dependência! Caso contrário não funciona.

Apenas certifique-se de que sua chave pública está configurada no Github, como você faria normalmente.

Outro detalhe: quando você fizer deploy desse projeto, é normal você não conseguir acessá-lo da instância de produção (ou desenvolvimento) porque o projeto é privado. Nesse caso, não esqueça de configurar uma *deploy key* para seu projeto privado.

Quanto aos pontos 2 e 3: não, não é possível usar projetos privados no Packagist.

Comment: Ajudou muito, já consegui usar o repositório do git com o composer, graças a acima, eu usava o svn e csv, mas não havia um controle muito rígido, funcionavam mais como backup. Estou tomando uma surra do git, mas caminhando. Vou ver depois o que é o Deploy Key e se tem uma forma de eu não ter que autorizar cada dispositivo, tentei usando o options ssh2 com chave publica e privada mas não consegui fazer funcionar. mais uma vez obrigado!